# Android datepicker showing white view like dialog title in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

How to remove that white view title coming in `DialogFragment` of `DatePickerDialog`

[image]

here is my DialogFragment code for reference :

```
public class DatePickerFrgDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerFrgDialog and return it
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {


    }
```

If anyone came across this issue, than please share the solution.

Comment: try this ` mProjectsDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: nope. didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
     @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

      // request a dialog without the title
      dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
      DatePickerDialog date_picker_dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
      date_picker_dialog.setTitle("");
      return dialog;
    }
```

use :

```
date_picker_dialog.setTitle("");
```

or :

```
date_picker_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: if i use this `date_picker_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` title comes back. if i use this `date_picker_dialog.setTitle("")` then it works